# computer crashes when doing calculations on big datasets on python using Dask

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I am unable to do calculations on large datasets using python-Dask. My computer crashes.

I have a computer with 4GB of RAM and running Linux Debian. I am trying load some files from a Kaggle competition (ElO Merchant competition) When I try load and get the shape of the dask dataframe the computer crashes.

I am running the code on only my laptop. I chose dask because it could handle large datasets. I would also like to know if Dask is able to move computations to my hard disk if it does not fit in memory? If so do I need to activate such thing or dask automatically does it? If I need to do it manually how do I do it? If there is a tutorial on this it would be great also.

I have 250GB Solid State Drive as my hard Disk. Hence the there would be space for a large dataset to fit to disk.

Please help me on this regard. My code is as below.

Thank you

Michael

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
from sklearn.externals.joblib import parallel_backend
client = Client(processes=False)

merchant = dd.read_csv('/home/michael/Elo_Merchant/merchants.csv')
new_merchant_transactions = dd.read_csv('/home/michael/Elo_Merchant/new_merchant_transactions.csv')
historical_transactions = dd.read_csv('/home/michael/Elo_Merchant/historical_transactions.csv')
train = dd.read_csv('/home/michael/Elo_Merchant/train.csv')
test = dd.read_csv('/home/michael/Elo_Merchant/test.csv')

merchant.head()
merchant.compute().shape
merchant_headers = merchant.columns.values.tolist()

for c in range(len(merchant_headers)): 
    print(merchant_headers[c])
    print('--------------------')
    print("{}".format(merchant[merchant_headers[c]].value_counts().compute()) + '\n')
    print("Number of NaN values {}".format(merchant[merchant_headers[c]].isnull().sum().compute()) + '\n')

historical_transactions.head()
historical_transactions.compute().shape #after computing for a few minutes computer restarts.
```

I expect it to run as the code and give me the shape of the dask array and run the rest of the code (which I have not showed here since it is not relevant)

Comment: Try `merchant.compute().shape` -> `merchant.shape.compute()` or `len(merchant)` ? You should look up what `compute()` does.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get it. 
Here it is:

```
print("(%s,%s)" % (historical_transactions.index.count().compute(),len(historical_transactions.columns)))
```

The first output  value is the rows and the second output value is the number of columns.

Thanks

Michael